# Magnifying glass appearing in a wrong way when I'm using AVPlayerLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, avplayerlayer

I am using an AVPlayerLayer to play video in the background of my UIViewController instance. When I launched my app on the iPhone I noticed that magnifying glass appearing in a wrong way. Video specifications: H.264, AAC, 640x360, MOV.

[image]

The background inside magnifying glass drawing without my video sublayer. Only subviews (buttons, text fields, etc.) are drawing inside my magnifying glass.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bf4" withExtension:@"mov"];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    container.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:container];

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    [container.layer addSublayer:layer];
    layer.frame = container.bounds;
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.textField];        
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [player play];
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: can you show us the screenshot of it?

Comment: @T_77 I've added screenshot. Check this out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one solution I figured out is to:

1. Put `UIImageView` below `container` view:

   ```
   self.containerThumbnail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
   self.containerThumbnail.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
   self.containerThumbnail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [self.view insertSubview:self.containerThumbnail belowSubview:container];
   ```
2. Become a time observer to the media player:

   ```
    CMTime bgInterval = CMTimeMake(1, 10);
   __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
   [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:bgInterval 
                                        queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)
                                   usingBlock:^(CMTime time)
   {
       [weakSelf locateThumbnail:time];
   }];
   ```
3. Put snapshots inside your `UIImageView`:

   ```
   - (void)locateThumbnail:(CMTime)time
   {
       __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
           CGImageRef imageRef = [weakSelf.imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
           CGImageRelease(imageRef);
           __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
               strongSelf.containerThumbnail.image = image;
           });
       });
   }
   ```

The property `imageGenerator` is of type `AVAssetImageGenerator`:

```
imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
```

N.B. Snapshots updates in the background and because of this frames lag behind the video. But this is better than nothing.